# Use Jade as angular2 template engine

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, pug, mean-stack

I'm currently trying to migrate to developing MEAN apps with Angular2 in place of Angular1.x but i'm currently having an issue based on using jade/pug as my template engine in angular2. I saw a post on how to implement this with webpack, but that tutorial is meant for another project structure and not the official angular/cli. So i'm asking if there's a way jade/pug can be used as template engine with the angular/cli project structure?

Answer (score 2):

Integrating **Pug** with **angular/cli** is pretty easy.

All you need to do is:

- Install [pug-cli](https://github.com/pugjs/pug-cli) using `npm install pug-cli --save-dev`
- Add a new `script` line into your `package.json`'s scripts: `"puggy": "pug src -P -w"`.
- Edit your `start` task, or create a new one, to first run `puggy` and then `serve`: `"dev": "npm run puggy & ng serve"`.

Your `package.json` should look like this:

```
"scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "puggy": "pug src -P -w",
    "dev": "npm run puggy & ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  }
```

Now, simply run `npm run dev`, or whatever name you gave to the task, in your terminal and you should see all of your `.pug` files getting compiled/watched/rendered and then everything served up.

I suggest you to add all of your `.html` files into your `.gitignore` adding `/src/**/*.html` into it and only pushing `.pug` files to your repo. Make sure you remove cached `.html` files using `git rm --cached *.html`.

Now you'll be able to write a form like

```
form(novalidate, '#f'='ngForm', '(ngSubmit)'='onSignin(f)')
```

And compile it into it's html

```
<form novalidate="novalidate" #f="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="onSignin(f)"></form>
```